# Calculating time complexity of algorithm

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

How to calculate time complexity of function f?

```
void f(int n)
{
    if (n <= 1)
       return;
    g(n, n / 3);
}

void g(int n, int m)
{
    int i = 1;
    while (m < n) {
       m += i;
       i++;
    }
    f(n / 2);
}
```

The answer is sqrt(n), but I don't see how...

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, note that the the program can be translated now to a single function program, by inlining `g(n,m)` in `f()`:

```
void f(int n)
{
    if (n <= 1)
       return;
    m = n/3;
    while (m < n) {
       m += i;
       i++;
    }
    f(n / 2);
}
```

The inner loop runs in `O(sqrt(n))` iteration, because it starts from `n/3`, ends with `n`, and is increased by 1,2,3,... so if we sum it we get:

```
n/3 + (1 + 2 + ... + i) >= n
```

We need to solve the above equation to find the final value of `i`, and we get:

```
1 + 2 + ... + i >= 2n/3
```

From sum of arithmetic progression:

```
i(i+1)/2 >= 2n/3
```

From the above inequality, [we can conclude](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%28x%2B1%29%2F2%20%3E%3D%202n%2F3) that indeed `i` is in `O(sqrt(n))`.

So, we can denote the complexity as:

```
T(n) = T(n/2)              +           O(sqrt(n))
        ^                                ^
    recursive step                 syntatic sugar for some function
                                   which is in O(sqrt(n)).
```

Now, we can see that:

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + sqrt(n) = T(n/4) + sqrt(n/2) + sqrt(n) = ... =
     = sqrt(1) + ... + sqrt(n/2) + sqrt(n)
```

[And the above sum is in `O(sqrt(n))`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20sqrt%282%5Ex%29%2C%20x%3D1%20to%20log%28n%29%2Flog%282%29)

Comment: Is there any other way to see that i is O(sqrt(n)) , and that the sum is O(sqrt(n))?

Answer (score 0):

Let F<sub>n</sub> be the time complexity of `f(n)` and G<sub>n,m</sub> be the time complexity of `g(n,m)`.

G<sub>n,m</sub> = sqrt(n-m) + F<sub>n / 2</sub>

F<sub>n</sub> = G<sub>n,n/3</sub> = sqrt(n-n/3) + F<sub>n / 2</sub> = C sqrt(n) + F<sub>n/2</sub>

So the answer is sqrt(n).